# Wordpress posts 'Mine'

Tags: wordpress

Has anyone set wordpress post Mine as the default view in the list of posts?

[image]

If so how did you do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follows trick -

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
    global $typenow;
    // check post type
    if( 'post' !== $typenow )
        return;

    // Active Mine tab
    if( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) || !isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?post_type=post&author='. get_current_user_id() ) );
        exit();
    }   
});
```